# Mac OSX. Storing data on app package, good idea?

Tags: macos

I am designing a small app for Mac OSX with little requirements and thinking on the simplest (in terms of laving the system clean) place to store status of the program. A candidate location could be in a specific folder in the app package, this way you don't create any other folders, user can uninstall simply erasing the package etc. Do you think that this is a god I dea or will find problems (privileges probably)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An app package should be read only:

- a package installed in /Applications is usable by any user.
- a package installed in /Users/Shared does not reflect in one user's session the preferences of the previous user

The best place for storing app status is in ~/Library/Application Support/MyApp/